# Why is my compiled c++ code already an executable without having to run "chmod a+x" beforehand?

Tags: c++, gcc

I was following this tutorial on GNU compilers found [here](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html#zz-2.) which does some simple compiling of a "hello world" c++ script "hello.cpp" by doing:

```
$ g++ -o hello hello.cpp 
$ chmod a+x hello
$ ./hello
```

And it made me realise with the limited knowledge of compiling I have that I sometimes have to specify my output as an executable using "chmod a+x" and sometimes its already an executable without it (which was the case for me when I ran the above).

Is it perhaps a version thing of g++ perhaps?

Comment: I never had to do `chmod` manually.

Comment: Because g++ knows that you are building an executable file, and it sets permissions accordingly. You'd be best served by not reading dubious **tutorials**. Any compiler I have worked with always produced correctly permissioned executables.

Comment: Agree with @HolyBlackCat. Never had to do that.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that the tutorial you are following is more authoritative than your own experiences? (Don't believe everything you read on the internet.)

Comment: I've never needed to do that.

Comment: This might help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66503/how-does-gcc-handle-file-permissions

Comment: Only had to do this when cross-compiling and then moving the compiled program onto a target with radically different permissions. Building on Windows and running on Linux, for example.

Answer (score 1):

`chmod a+x` is mere a way to explicitly make sure it is an executable file. Not all compilers will definitely make the file executable, adding an explicit command to make it executable will make the script work with any compiler too chain. I think it is a good way, although seemingly redundant for gcc.